# USB3.0 network cards: worth buying?

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

So, my current laptop is an ethernetless "ultrabook"  with a rather poor built-in wifi, and this causes problems (unacceptable ping in online FPS games, reconnects, etc). Cheap external USB wifi is also not a solution *(here's a lot of spectrum pollination caused by tens or hundreds of access points in close proximity.. some hope for 802.11ac but I think it's not worth it)*.

Currently I am looking at StarTech's adapter (based on AXIS chip, Linux-supported).

It is known that USB2.0 transfer rate was related to the Ethernet's in a way, which had to limit transfer speed for packets (*"The problem is that Ethernet frames are about 1500 bytes in size—about 3 USB 2.0 packets, and 23 USB 1.1 packets, ...  there is bus latency, where nothing is sent until another transfer can be initiated.*" - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB#Protocols))

Question #1: what kind of ping/latency delays should I expect from such device? My wifi is currently doing 3-5ms to a host on same network (compare to 0.2ms on gigabit ethernet link)

Question #2: are these adapters require to re-plug them each hour, if network stops working?

Comment: @DaveRook I buy that, I run that, I share that, I still visit Superuser?

Comment: round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.249/0.336/1.706/0.099 ms. But I agree the wording could be improved.